# How to dynamically retrieve data from database

Tags: database, winforms

I am working on the functionality of mail merge on winform using C#. As its known it in mail merge an email is sent to the batch. To serve this purpose the data list is created and its stored in database, when user pressess the "Insert and merge" option the data is retrieved from DB and replaces the place holders.
The query used is;

comm.CommandText="select <> from <> where Sno=1;

where Sno is primary key

The question is, How can I do it dynamically

int rec=1;

I want to replace "1" with this variable, how can I do it?

Comment: Use a parameter. You should update this question with the specific database you are using so people can accurately suggest an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
comm.Commandtext = "Select <> from <> where Sno=@SNO";
comm.Parameters.Add("@SNO", rec);
```